# ¿Por qué sale la alerta "Uncaught ReferenceError: Marcelo is not defined " si en mi codigo esta definida la variable candidatoUno?

Tags: javascript

```js
const candidatoUno = Marcelo;
const candidatoDos = Alan;
const candidatoTres = Alicia;

let totalVotosCandidatoUno = 70;
let totalVotosCandidatoDos = 30;
let totalVotosCandidatoTres = 20;
let totalVotos =totalVotosCandidatoUno+totalVotosCandidatoDos+totalVotosCandidatoTres;


let total1 = Math.round((totalVotosCandidatoUno*100)/totalVotos);
console.log(total1);
let total2 = Math.round((totalVotosCandidatoDos*100)/totalVotos);
console.log(total2);
let total3 = Math.round((totalVotosCandidatoTres*100)/totalVotos);
console.log(total3);

if (totalVotosCandidatoUno >= 51 ) {
   
    console.log(`el nuevo Presidente del Centro de Estudiantes de la Universidad Americana es: 
    ${candidatoUno}  con la cantidad de ${totalVotosCandidatoUno} votos.`)
}
```

Quisiera saber porque me sale esta  alerta "Uncaught ReferenceError: Marcelo is not defined " si en mi codigo esta definido la variable candidatoUno

Comment: Sucede que estás asignando una variable llamada `Marcelo` como el valor de tu variable `candidatoUno`, pero como la variable `Marcelo` no existe, ahí el error. Deben ser strings, entonces encierra entre `""` al valor de tus 3 variables (`"Marcelo"`, `"Alan"`, `"Alicia"`) y lo tienes, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alfabravo!! se me paso algo tan basico me disculpo por esta pregunta tan tonta

Answer (score 2):

Lo que te está ocurriendo es que estás usando JS y el valor del tipo de dato tiene que ser string, lo tendrías que poner así:

```
const candidatoUno = 'Marcelo';
const candidatoDos = 'Alan';
const candidatoTres = 'Alicia';
```

Comment: Gracias Alan!!! ahora me di cuenta de mi falta de desatencion